# closure = union of the set and the set of limit points

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ and denote the set of limit points of
>   $S$ as $S'$.
>
> Show that $S \cup S' = \bar{S}$ where $\bar{S}$ is the closure.

(i) I want to show that $\bar{S} \subseteq S \cup S'$ .

Let $x \in \bar{S}$ then either $x \in S$ or $x \in \bar{S}\backslash S $.

If $x \in S$ then $x \in S \cup S'$

If $x \in \bar{S}\backslash S $ ...?

(ii) I want to show that $S \cup S' \subseteq \bar{S}$.

Let $x \in S \cup S'$. Then, $x \in S$ or $x \in S'$.

If $x\in S$ then $x \in \bar{S}$.

If $x \in \bar{S}$ ... ?

Thank you

Comment: Since $S$ is a subset of $S'$, all you need to prove is that $S'=\bar S$. To do that, first, can you tell us which definition of closure are you working with?

Comment: @5xum $S$ is in general not a subset of $S'$, $S$ can have isolated points.

Comment: @user120227 what are you using for your definition of closure?

Comment: The best way to show this is by contradiction, start with a contradicting assumption and the rest is just straightforward.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Definition I am using is $\bar{S}$ = smallest closed subset of $ \mathbb{R^n}$ which contains $S$

Comment: @user120227 and what are you using for your definition of closed? Just  what you have written as the title?

Comment: @DanielFischer for every point $x\in S$, take the sequence $a_n$ where $\forall n: a_n = x$. Then the limit of $a_n$ is $x$, so $x\in S'$, is it not?

Comment: @5xum it requires [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) to be a limitpoint.

Comment: @5xum It's confusing terminology. A limit point of a set $S$ is an $x$, such that for every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ the set $S\cap (U\setminus\{x\})$ is non-empty. That's different from limit points of sequences.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at (i) you're almost done.  If $x \in \overline{S} \backslash S$ then $x \notin S$ and since $x \in \overline{S}$ then all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ intersect $S$.  But since $x$ is not in $S$ then $U$ must intersect $S$ at some point other point that is not $x$.  Thus $x \in S'$.  Therefore you can conclude that $\overline{S} \underline{\subset} S \cup S'$.

For (ii) note that if $x \in S \cup S'$ then all neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ intersect $S$ at some point, doesn't matter where.  Thus $x \in \overline{S}$.  Therefore $S \cup S' \underline{\subset} \overline{S}$.

The final conclusion being that $S \cup S' = \overline{S}$

(This is a general result in topology that you can reformulate to real euclidean space if you wish)

Comment: It looks like your definition of $\overline S$ is that $x \in \overline S$ if every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ intersects S. Is this equivalent to the definition that $\overline S$ is the intersection of all **closed** sets containing $S$? Or have I understood you wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to show that $S \cup S' \subset \overline{S}$. Choose $x \in S \cup S'$. If $x \in S$, then clearly $x \in \overline{S}$. So supppose instead that $x \in S'$. Suppose that $x \notin \overline{S}$. Since this is a closed set, its complement is open, and so there is some neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $U \cap \overline{S} = \emptyset$. In particular, $U \cap S = \emptyset$. It should hopefully be not too hard to see that this contradicts the idea of $x$ being a limit point of $S$ (take a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$...).

For the converse, Suppose $x \in \overline{S}$ but that $x \notin S$. Choose balls $U_n$ of radius $1/n$ centered at $x$. Since $x \in \overline{S}$, these will each have non-empty intersection with $S$ (check this!). From here you should be able to build the desired sequence in $S$ which converges to $x$, and so shows that $x$ is a limit point of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x\in X$ is a limit point of $A .$ First we note that $\mathrm{int}A \subset A \subset \overline{A} .$ 
Because $A \subset \overline{A}, $ if $x \in A$ then obviously $x \in \overline{A} $. If $ x \notin A ,$ since $x$ is a limit point of $A$, any open $O$ set containing $x$ has the property $ O \cap A \ne \emptyset $ and $  O \cap (X-A)\ne \emptyset $. This means that $x \in \partial A.$ Because $\partial A \subset \overline{A} ,$ we have that $x\in \overline{A}.$

Now suppose $ x \in \overline{A}$. If $x \notin \mathrm{int}A, $ then $x \in \partial A$. Then every open set $O$ containing $x$ has point $y \in A$ and $y\ne x .$ This means $x$ is a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

Reply for the comment in the highest score answer:
Suppose $X$ is topology space, $p\in X, A\subset X$, denote the interior, exterior, boundary and closure of $A$ as $A^o, A^e, \partial A$ and $\overline{A}$ respectively. Then $\overline{A}=A^o\cup \partial A= X\backslash A^e$, that is for any nbd. $U$ of $p$, $U\notin X\backslash A\Rightarrow$ $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$.

Definition Used
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what you are using as your definition of closed, but one very common definition is: A set S is closed iff it contains all its limit points. If that is a definition you are using or can use, this proof should be easier.

$\underline{Show: S\cup S' \subseteq \bar S}$: If $x \in S$ then we know $x \in \bar S$ as $S \subseteq \bar S$. If $x \in S'$ then $x \in \bar S$ because $\bar S$ contains all its limit points. Thus $S\cup S' \subseteq \bar S$.

$\underline{Show: \bar S \subseteq S\cup S'}$: Let $x \in \bar S$. We know either $x \in S$ or $x \in \bar S - S$. The first case is trivial, so we will focus on any $x \in \bar S - S$. Since $x\notin S$ but $x \in \bar S$, $x$ must be a limit point of $S$. Thus $x \in S'$. This establishes that for any $x \in \bar S$ either $x\in S$ or $x \in S'$, so $\bar S \subseteq S\cup S' $.